# Add clipping to THREE.ShaderMaterial

Tags: three.js, glsl

I'm trying to create a shader that takes into account the clipping planes I'm defining in the scene.  These clipping planes work fine for all of the 'vanilla' materials I'm using: `THREE.MeshLambertMaterial`, `THREE.MeshPhongMaterial`, and `THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial`, but `THREE.ShaderMaterial` is missing this implementation.  This is an example of what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/fraguada/27LrLsv5/

In this example there are two cubes, one with a `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial` and one with a material defined by `THREE.ShaderMaterial`.  The cube with a `THREE.MeshStandardMaterial` clips ok.  The cube with THREE.ShaderMaterial does not clip.

(I'm not typically defining the vertex/fragment shader in script tags as I show in the jsfiddle, instead I'm defining them in a similar manner to this: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/dev/examples/js/shaders/BasicShader.js.)

So, a few questions:

1. Should THREE.ShaderMaterial include Clipping Planes out of the box? (there is a clipping property, but not sure what it enables)
2. If not, how could I modify this shader to include the necessary params and shader chunks to enable clipping?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually, **clipping is done inside the *Three.js* shaders**.

To make it work, you have to handle it inside your shader, by adding those 4 *"shader chunks"* :

- [`clipping_planes_pars_vertex.glsl`](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/clipping_planes_pars_vertex.glsl) at the top of your vertex shader ;
- [`clipping_planes_vertex.glsl`](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/clipping_planes_vertex.glsl) inside the `main()` of your vertex shader ;
- [`clipping_planes_pars_fragment.glsl`](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/clipping_planes_pars_fragment.glsl) at the top of your fragment shader ;
- [`clipping_planes_fragment.glsl`](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/clipping_planes_fragment.glsl) inside the `main()` of your fragment shader.

You can access those chunks by simply adding `#include <(chunk name)>` to your shaders.

Then, set `material.clipping = true;` and it should work.

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we7c90rx/4/).

---

**Note**

To make your shader work, I also added [`begin_vertex.glsl`](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/begin_vertex.glsl) and [`project_vertex.glsl`](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderChunk/project_vertex.glsl).

I checked the current [phong shader implementation](https://github.com/neeh/three.js/blob/dev/src/renderers/shaders/ShaderLib/meshphong_vert.glsl) to understand where to put those chunks.

---

**Note 2**

This code should work with a shader implemented with an array of strings but note that you can also reference shader chunks with `THREE.ShaderChunk[(chunk name)]`.
This should be more suitable in your case.

Comment: Thanks @neeh, this was driving me a bit nuts.  I was missing the begin_vertex and project_vertex chunks!  I kept getting errors related to `mvPosition`but I hadn't zero'ed in on the chunk that defined that.  Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks!! MOST IMPORTANT part of this answer is that the property to set is `clipping` for the ShaderMaterial... not present in the other materials. https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/ShaderMaterial

Comment: updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/we7c90rx/4/ fixes broken OrbitControls instantiation (and adds `PlaneHelper` to make clipping a little more clear)

Comment: @neeh thanks bro, you made my day even in 2020. I didn't know I have to enable the `clipping` in the shaderMaterial. Thanks :)

Comment: Updated fiddle to use new three.js imports: https://jsfiddle.net/kyleawayan/3L8jmpde/10/