# clipping planes in forge viewer not able to clip objects with ShaderMaterial

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, forge

I am trying to add custom objects with `THREE.ShaderMaterial` in forge-viewer, I am able to add and render the objects in forge-viewer's `overlayScene`.

I referred [this](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2017/01/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1.html) blog for adding the same.

The problem I am facing is: 
The forge-viewer's clipping planes are not able to clip the custom added objects.
If I try to add same object with other material, then clipping planes are able to clip them.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42532545/add-clipping-to-three-shadermaterial). But I am getting error that `Cannot resolve #include<clipping_planes_pars_vertex.glsl>` (same for other shader sources). I have tried to add these shaders in `THREE.ShaderChunk` but not worked.

I have seen that the error comes from in `ShaderChunk.ts` because it didn't found shader in `chunks[]`.

1. Is there any way to use clipping planes with `THREE.ShaderMaterial`?
2. Do I need to add my custom shaders in `chunks[]` from `ShaderChunk.ts`?  If yes How?

Please share a demo example if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similarly to the other Stack Overflow question you found, the section tool in Forge Viewer uses a custom shader logic that is only included in the Viewer's own materials. Try including the following snippets in your material shaders:

In the vertex shader:

```
...
#if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
    varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
#endif
...
void main() {
    ...
    #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
        vWorldPosition = vec3(/* include your own vertex world position here */);
    #endif
    ...
}
...
```

In the fragment shader:

```
...
#if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
    varying highp vec3 vWorldPosition;
#endif

#include<cutplanes>
...
void main() {
    ...
    #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
        checkCutPlanes(vWorldPosition);
    #endif
    ...
}
...
```

And when defining the new `THREE.ShaderMaterial`, you also need to include a couple of sectioning-specific uniforms:

```
const uniforms = {
    ...
    "cutplanes": { type: "v4v", value: [] },
    "hatchParams": { type: "v2", value: new THREE.Vector2(1.0, 10.0) },
    "hatchTintColor": { type: "c", value: new THREE.Color( 0xFFFFFF ) },
    "hatchTintIntensity": { type: "f", value: 1.0 },
    ...
}
```

See this [gist](https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/495ce7569a52b458955b71641452c9dc/revisions) for a complete example of adding sectioning support to a `THREE.ShaderMaterial`.

Comment: I have tried this but not worked, below are my vertex and fragment shaders:

Comment: const vertexShader = `#if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0 varying vec3 vWorldPosition; #endif attribute vec4 color; varying vec4 vColor; void main() { vec4 vPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0); gl_Position = projectionMatrix * vPosition; vColor = color; #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0 vWorldPosition = vec3(projectionMatrix * vPosition); #endif };`

Comment: const fragmentShader = `#if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
    varying highp vec3 vWorldPosition;
#endif
#include<cutplanes>

#ifdef GL_ES
precision highp float;
#endif
varying vec4 vColor;
void main() {
 gl_FragColor = vColor;
 
 #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
  checkCutPlanes(vWorldPosition);
 #endif
}; `

Comment: Don’t multiply vWorldPosition with projection matrix. It should by just set to vPosition.xyz

Comment: No, not worked.
Could you please share an small complete example?

Comment: Can you please prepare a gist with a complete version of your vertex shader and fragment shader? The code you pasted here doesn't seem to be complete, for example, in the vertex shader you're referencing `position` variable that's not declared anywhere.

Comment: Could you please refer shaders from  https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-viewer-custom-shaders-part-1 ,we don't need to declare `modelViewMatrix ,projectionMatrix` and `position` they are predefines in libraries and automatically copy our values, Here position contains my vertex coords.

Comment: Thanks @Pravin, I've made a new revision to Philippe's gist that adds support for sectioning: https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/495ce7569a52b458955b71641452c9dc/revisions. Note that, apart from the changes to the VS and FS, you also need to include a couple of sectioning-related shader uniforms.

Comment: Awesome! Glad I could help :)