# Make cutplanes work with custom Meshes in ForgeViewer

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm using Autodesk's ForgeViewer to load both IFC files and custom THREE.js meshes similar to what is done [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/02/custom-transparent-meshes-with-view-data-api.html)

The problem I'm having is that the cutplanes ([see e.g. here](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#getcutplanes)) are not affecting the custom meshes, only the Forge models. Is there any way that I can make the cutplanes work on the custom meshes as well?

If I'm not mistaken, the THREE.js's way of setting `clippingPlanes` was not introduced yet in the r71 version (Which Forge's custom implementation is based off of) but perhaps there's a Forge specific way of making this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on Petr's answer, here's the code necessary for supporting cutplanes for textured meshes:

```
const imgTexture = THREE_FORGE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(textureUrl);

const vertexShader = `
  #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
      varying vec3 vWorldPosition;
  #endif
  varying vec2 vUv;
  void main() {
      #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
          vec4 _worldPosition = modelMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );
          vWorldPosition = _worldPosition.xyz;
      #endif
      vUv = uv;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position,1.0);
  }
`;

const fragmentShader = `
  #include<cutplanes>
  #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
      varying highp vec3 vWorldPosition;
  #endif
  uniform sampler2D texture;
  varying vec2 vUv;
  void main() {
      #if NUM_CUTPLANES > 0
          checkCutPlanes(vWorldPosition);
      #endif
      gl_FragColor = texture2D(texture, vUv);
  }
`;

const material = new THREE_FORGE.ShaderMaterial({
    uniforms: {
        cutplanes: {type: 'v4v', value: []},
        hatchParams: {type: 'v2', value: new THREE_FORGE.Vector2(1.0, 10.0)},
        hatchTintColor: {type: 'c', value: new THREE_FORGE.Color(0xFFFFFF)},
        hatchTintIntensity: {type: 'f', value: 1.0},
        texture: {type: 't', value: imgTexture},
    },
    vertexShader: vertexShader,
    fragmentShader: fragmentShader,
});

const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're right, Forge Viewer uses its own shader-based clipping. See my other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52221315/clipping-planes-in-forge-viewer-not-able-to-clip-objects-with-shadermaterial) (especially this [gist](https://gist.github.com/petrbroz/495ce7569a52b458955b71641452c9dc/revisions)) for more details.